# What are the units of $f/f_s$?

Tags: discussion

Which is sometimes called the normalized frequency.

Is it unitless?

$$ \frac{f \; Hz }{f_s \; Hz } = \frac{f}{f_s} $$

Or not?

$$ \frac{f \; \frac{cycles}{second} }{f_s \; \frac{samples}{second} } = \frac{f}{f_s} \frac{cycles}{sample} $$

According to Dimensional Analysis, $ \frac{cycles}{second} $ (aka Hz) and $\frac{samples}{second}$ are both $sec^{-1}$ and the normalized frequency is dimensionless, so it is silent on the issue.

The problem with that is the other common definition of normalized frequency has units of $ \frac{radians}{sample} $ which is also dimensionless.

Sampling is a repeated discrete task, it is not cyclical.  It has a rate, not a frequency.

If I multiply the sampling rate by a time interval do I get cycles or samples?

$$ N \; samples  = f_s \; \frac{samples}{second} \cdot t \; seconds $$

I don't think I've ever seen someone say "The DFT frame is 32 cycles long", yet when you call the sampling rate a frequency that is what you are saying.

So, can anyone give a justification for calling it sampling frequency other than ad populum.  And, if you can't, why should the deacons of a discipline (I'm talking about the regulars here) propagate a bad practice?

This is more of a deepster question than it appears.  Please don't give a fired from the hip response.  Think about it a bit first.

---

I've elaborated a little bit on this in a question:

[DFT exercise in the book Understanding digital signal processing 3 Ed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/dft-exercise-in-the-book-understanding-digital-signal-processing-3-ed/69233#69233)

Well, actually taking the point a little bit further.  I think it is damaging to teach the DFT strictly in the context of Seconds and Hertz as units.  One should not expect a first time learner to be able to differentiate the tool from its application.  There have been too many "Where do I plug in the Hertz when looking for repeat patterns in ...." (Paraphrasing).

It doesn't help that most the used MATLAB calls seem to Hertz and Seconds oriented either.

So, if you are an educator of this material, in any setting, please keep this in mind.

---

Response to Fat32's comment in RB-J's answer.

Actually I am coming at this form an epistemological direction.  I am well aware of the goal of DA (Dimensional Analysis) to achieve conceptual harmony to the natural physical constants (and approaching this goal is contrary to integrity checking of equations).

My objection is to RB-J's role as an acolyte insisting that DA is "the only and true way" (and his combative manner).  Particularly since it was formalized by a "standards committee" (those with experience, insert running jokes here).  Whether rotation should be a dimension was and probably still is a big issue to wank over.  DA's definitions of "Dimension" and "Unit" are the pedantic ones and I would think minority ones.  The carrying-the-units/math/common man definitions are much more down-to-earth (more concrete than abstract).  A dimension is a coordinate in a vector space, and a unit defines a measure along that coordinate.

So, if you want to use DA to find "meaning in Physics", fine.  But if you are looking for integrity checking to prevent calculation errors in formulas, you aren't using the best tool.  The lander crashed because "velocity" wasn't defined in units.  And I challenge you to assert the following equation is nonsense with the carry the units definition of a unit:

$$ 2 \frac{\text{Semicircles}}{\text{Circle}} \cdot 1 \frac{\text{Circle}}{\text{Cycle}}  \cdot \pi \frac{\text{Radians}}{\text{Semicircle}} = 2 \pi \frac{\text{Radians}}{\text{Cycle}} $$

Two kilos of apples is different than two kilos of oranges, so if you are weighing them, I kilo of apples weighs a kilo (conversion factor), and I kilo of oranges weighs a kilo (conversion factor), so you can add them (common units).   Note, no need to mention dimension.  If you are counting them, well you have so many apples (units) and so many oranges (units).  If you want to compare items of different units, you have to convert them to the same scale (units) using what is known as a "Value Function".  The value function can be as simple as multiplying by a conversion factor (even if that factor is numerically 1).  "Pricing" is the most common value function there is.  Yes, carrying the units was developed mainly for use in "rate problems" to keep your units straight and it works well.

The difference between carrying the units vs DA is like weak typing vs strong typing in programming languages.

So, deepster/fancy question du jour:  If the Universe didn't exist, would the values of $\pi$ and $e$ still exist?

---

I hope everybody agrees that this is a definitional issue, so I'd like to attempt to take the "my definition is right" aspect out of this, and shift to the implications of accepting either definition as the correct one.  To do so, I'm going to introduce two working definitions with the intention that the scope not exceed the extent of the this question and its answers, and that the nomenclature not favor one over the other.

t-units = Traditional units, using the root meaning of "one", capable of any level of specificity by the act of naming.

s-units = Standardized units, as defined by the various ISO standards or other governing bodies

There should be no disagreement about the following statements:

1. s-units are a subset of t-units
2. In t-units, the answer to the title question is cycles per sample
3. In s-units, the answer to the title question is unitless
4. Converting from t-units to s-units can be, and often is, lossy

Three questions arise from these observations:

A.  Should t-units be stamped out?

B.  Was it the intent of standardization to weaken the integrity validation capability of Dimensional/Unit Analysis?

C.  How does this relate to "political correctness" in general?

Indeed, this is a pedantic (in a non-perjorative way) exercise, done in pedantic style.  That's the point of it being placed in Meta and tagged with "discussion".

---

Okay, everybody can see the setup, right?

Check-mate.

Observation 4 validates Question B.  Question B is a yes/no question.  So what can be answered?

No, it is an unintended consequence.  Okay, you admit that it is detrimental to integrity checking.

Yes, it is intentional as it keeps things simple [A strong aversion to complexity has repeatedly been expressed here] and any loss of functionality is a small price to pay for the greater good of the benefits of standardization.

In either case, it is clear that a loss of validity has occurred.  Therefore the answer to Question A has to be a firm no.  Furthermore, those who attempt to do so are firmly in the wrong and should desist immediately, starting with RB-J.

Question C takes us to a whole 'nuther level.  This is totalitarianism in one of its many forms.  I will fight it where ever I see it.  This is called the "good fight".

It is natural that engineers be attracted to technocracy, but you have to resist its siren song or you will surely crash on the rocks.

I believe in the dignity of critters, including biped furless chimps.  It is institutions of all forms that need to have restrictive behavioral binds, not individuals.

I told you this would be deep, and yes, I am a "lousy judge of my own expertise", but isn't everyone?

Comment: <<mindblown emoji>>

Comment: @PeterK. You're welcome.  Merry Christmas  ;-)  I thought meta would be the right place to throw down the gauntlet.  I got a little peeved this morning about a down vote on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62812/sampling-xt-cos4-pi-t-cos2-pi-t which I suspect is due to some one thin skinned not liking my P.S.  The deeper question here is should a bad practice be tolerated because it has been the norm?  Or should it be corrected?  This applies to any discipline.

Comment: FWIW, I think sampling has a rate, not a frequency. Sometimes I do say "sampling frequency" out of laziness and/or to avoid dealing with the units (for example, how to properly state Nyquist's sampling theorem, which compares a frequency with a rate?) I tend to just avoid the issue, but I think you're right, we should deal with it. I'm not sure what's the best way.

Comment: @MBaz, frequencies are rates.  the two notions are one-and-the-same.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The way I understand it, frequency is a rate, but not all rates are frequencies. Frequencies are measured in Hz (cycles per second), but rates can have any units.

Comment: @MBaz, if it's a rate in time then it's the number of occurrences of *something* per unit time.  The dimension is $\mathrm{T}^{-1}$ and the common unit is $\mathrm{s}^{-1}$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson There is an old joke: "A topologist is a mathematician who can't tell the difference between his coffee cup and his donut." Let's revise it some, "A practitioner of DA, RB-J style, is a poser who can't tell the difference between widgets coming off an assembly line, children playing on a merry-go-round, or Jupiter." Units come first, then they can be categorized by dimension which has a default unit. The categorization does not invalidate, supercede, or destroy the identification.  Your orientation is backward here as well.  Every conversion factor is also a rate.

Comment: (con't) The notion that a catergorization should be adequate for identification is what make nondimensional units so problematic.  It's a ludicrous aspiration.  Besides a simple search will tell you that the real DA dimension is $L^0 M^0 T^{-1}$. Or you can really wank it and go the full 8 dimension set, or should that be 9?   Sigh.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I know that the SI defines Hz as $s^{-1}$, but I have an intellectual problem using Hz for _something_ over time (except cycles). For example, nobody uses Hz for speed (where _something_ is a meter). Nobody uses Hz for data rate (where _something_ is a bit -- which is not even an SI derived unit). Radians per second need to be sort of special-cased (here _something_ is a radian, but somehow you need a $2\pi$ to convert to Hz). The becquerel is defined as one Hz ($\text{Bq} = s^{-1}$) but nobody says "this sample has 20 Hz of radiation".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  So, from a practical engineering persepective, and with my limited understanding, measuring _anything_ (except cycles) per second using herz makes little sense. At least this is my perspective, which I acknowledge may be limited by my personal way of interpreting the world.

Comment: So, my approach is to make up the units I need (radians, frames, samples, bits, bit errors, frame errors, etc; send complaints to the SI) and divide them by time. I reserve Hz exclusively for signal frequency, and bandwidth.

Comment: I concur with @MBaz approach and find it very confusing the notion that we should NOT use radians and cycles as units (still trying to get my head around that) but as Cedron says for purpose of DA and even more specifically computer checking of unit consistency it makes a lot of sense to include and not say it it unitless. This was an interesting read: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0026-1394/52/1/40/pdf

Comment: So it is of course unitless because SI says so, and when we restrict ourselves to the rules of SI that is indeed so and likely with good purpose tied to physical constants- but then in practical application for my own use of "units" I clearly see how that is flawed or not as useful. Interesting stuff I am still getting my head around. In the meantime units of fractional frequency for me will be cycles/sample and radians/sample.

Comment: If the question was stated "What are the SI Units of f/fs" then there would be no ambiguity in the answer, and it would be unitless.

Comment: @DanBoschen That paper is a good read, thatnks for the pointer!

Comment: @DanBoschen The problem is not about using *cycles* or *samples* sort of a unit designator; it's ok; it's used in practice for example in image processing where *cpm* (cycles per meter) refers to spatial frequency of image patterns. There we connot use Hz which strictly refers to *time* periodicity of an event. The problem is about making this a problem? The SI *dimension* of $f/f_s$ is none. Yet you can assign *anything* with $f$ and $f_s$ such as *f = periods/second* and *f_s = impulses / second* hence you will have *f/f_s = periods / impulse* as our new invention which we don't **need** :-)

Comment: @Fat32 not sure of that (yet not qualified to really answer; I am still getting my head around this so observing with technical interest). Your last point really doesn’t make sense to me since fs is indeed samples/second in contrast to a sine wave that is cycles/second. What I wouldn’t need is to assign something else like impulses but I do see the utility of samples. The fact that radians are unitless is at the core of my own confusion (if SI says that so be it but I would tend to agree that it is an unfortunate conclusion for my use of it), otherwise a cycle can be a derived unit scaled

Comment: from the radian. Did you read the paper I found? I thought they had an interesting angle as to how the radian could be given a unit by including it in the physical constants that are affected. Regardless I have to use it in my work in identical form to units, if it is not a unit them I’ll just call it a fake-unit and move on— but it greater interest to me is why it wasn’t included. If a radian is the distance along the circumference of one radius divided by the radius I see how the units disappear. But I could have also said a “foot” is the dist along my foot divided by the length of my foot

Comment: @DanBoschen it's shocking !!! How easy you accept *fs = samples/second* but that easy you reject *fs= impulse/second* while both have dimensons of 1/s, and an *impulse* is just another valid designator for a *sample* in impulse-modulated sampling.....  every *impulse* gives you a *sample* and number of samples is synonym with number of impulses... ;-))) fully consistent isn't it.

Comment: @Fat32 I don't reject that at all, that makes perfect sense-- It's just not a typical use describing the sampling rate in signal processing convention, so I think I would just confuse others if I chose to use that. Either Samples/sec or Impulses/sec are more useful for me than /sec. But sure, it still works, the normalized sampling rate would be cycles/impulse or radians/impulse-- I find nothing wrong with that

Comment: @Fat32 What is the meaning of "dimensions of 1/s" versus "units of 1/s"? As I said I am educating myself, not debating so perhaps it is something more specific to physics and physical constants that I am less familiar with. So is the normalized ratio simply dimensionless with units of cylces/sample?  Maybe that is the case https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/units-and-dimension#:~:text=Dimensions%20are%20physical%20quantities%20that,relative%20unit%20that%20describes%20length). I see the radian is a "derived unit" rather than a fundamental unit is SI,

Comment: So then aren't the "units" of radians/sec radians and seconds, and then how can we say that radians/sample is unitless, if anyone is saying that (for my education)? Or is anything that isn't one of the fundamental units is not allowed to be called a "unit"? Is this all semantics or is there an actual problem is using radians as a unit to ensure accurate computations/scaling etc? If it can't be a unit, what do we then call it to avoid the other problem whatever it is? This is definitely interesting.

Comment: @Fat32 I continued this under my own "answer" but it is more of a question

Comment: This post should be deleted for the sake of clarity... And may be asked again but with utmost clarity and one clear answer for all...

Comment: @Fat32 I have no problem with you posting a new question on the same topic and shifting the discussion there.  As I said earlier, this is a discussion I think is sorely needed.

Comment: @Fat32 What is "shocking!!!" is somebody declaring that two items in the same category are the same thing without adding the qualifier "categorically".  So saying samples and cycles (or samples and impulses) are the same thing is false.  Saying they are categorically the same is true (within the SI categorization scheme).  However, categorizing can be a lossy operation so employing it in validity checking weakens the validity checking.  So, is it safe to say your answer to Question C above in the OP is "small price to pay"?

Comment: @CedronDawg see my comment to RBJ's latest comment on his own answer...

Comment: @Fat32 Here's a cite that may be useful for everyone:  https://thebestschools.org/magazine/15-logical-fallacies-know/
$$ $$
Here are four that have been repeatedly employed:  Ad Hominem, Circular Argument, Appeal to Authority, Bandwagon Fallacy
$$ $$
I have said what intended to say, and it isn't about the units.  I have shown what I intended to show.  Feel free to start a new question on the carrier topic.  Don't expect me to.

Comment: @CedronDawg No I take it as a **hobby** ;-)))

Comment: @DanBoschen sorry I missed your comments... it's not only an *impulse* you could also say a *point* too! Just like N-point DFT (to mean N-sample DFT)... point, sample, impulse the same thing in this context :-) I caused a lot of confusions in this therad. I'm sorry for that. And repeating once more I believe that this threat should be deleted in its entirety. Then re-opened if OP wants to ask it again... But only **cited** answers should be given instead of *opinions*... That's the best way imho to resolve the issue. We're not gonna invent the units of f/fs here in dsp.se, are we ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cycles/sample is correct, and it is not unitless.  In those units, the *Nyquist frequency* is 0.5.  In units of radians/sample, the Nyquist frequency is $\pi$.  The Matlab functions I'm familiar with use units of cycles/half-sample, and the Nyquist frequency is 1.0.

Comment: Indeed, this is a rant against the use of the term "sampling frequency" and specifying the units as Hz, which is frequently (pun intended) done.  I recommend you follow the link where I elaborate a bit.  You may also find my answer here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69430/amplitude-after-fourier-transform/69432#69432 interesting as well.  BTW, welcome to DSP.SE.  You might also find my blog interesting:  https://www.dsprelated.com/blogs-1/nf/Cedron_Dawg.php  It's chock full of formulas you have probably never seen before.

Comment: This is absurd. f/fs does not have any units. It's just a number. No need to introduce absurd nomenclature. Now take a simple math example: consider a set of N=50 people with **heights** between 150 cms and 200 cms. Each person has a height of $x_i$ cms. (i is the order of person in the set). Let's compute the **average height** (say it's 175 cms.) $$ \mu = \frac{x_1 + x_2 +...+x_N}{N} = 175 cms $$ What's the unit of average **height**, of course *cms*. What's the unit of **N** ? It's a counting **number** without a unit. Hence, the unit of $\mu$ is in cms (or converted to feet, inch, yard).

Comment: (cont.) Now lets introduce a new metric, $\bar{x}_i$ for each person defined on the following :$$ \bar{x}_i = \frac{x_i}{\mu} $$ Now, what is the *unit* of $\bar{x}_i$? Both $x_i$ and $\mu$ has the units of **cms** so unit of $\bar{x}_i$ is nothing; it's unitless.Lets say for some $x_{7} = 175$ cms, then $\bar{x}_7= 1 $; what is this unit of $1$? 1 what? 1 cms? Of course not? you **may** denote it as **1 per mean-height** but NO! **mean-height** is just another name for the unit of **cms**. So, $f/f_s$ has no units but an association with $f_s$.

Comment: (cnt) This same convention is used everywhere in physics and engineering practice. We have quantities with units, and certain quantities (such as ratios of the same kind) without units. THere's no need to introduce awkward units for untless quantities (aka. numbers). This *same* thing is used in *Relativistic Calculations* where every speed is divided by $c$ (light-speed in m/s) to get *normalised speeds without units*. So if your speed is 0.5, then it's half light speed. But that 0.5 does not have a unit. If you have problems with unitless quantities, then go some physics department to argue.

Comment: @Fat32 I'm in Bob K.'s camp on this one.  It is entirely consistent with the "The factor-label method for converting units" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis.  Presenting a fallacious argument (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) that Physicists are the "Authoritay" isn't very convincing.  I have no problem with unitless quantities, I know what a Rayleigh number is.  I am sort of struggling with the Index of Refraction right now and if it is truly unitless.

Comment: (con't) The specificity of unit designation is kind of a subjective thing.  As long as you use two different names, you have two different units.  If there is a one-to-one correspondence, then there is a conversion factor with a magnitude of 1.  Whether this should be explicit or implicit is also subjective and context dependent.

Comment: @CedronDawg I think there's no need to make the problem bigger or wider than it actually is [if that's not to be used as tactic for blurring the truth]. The question was simple: What is the unit of $f/f_s$ where $f$ is the frequency (of some signal) and $f_s$ is the frequency of sampling (device). Both are designated with $Hz$ hence $f/f_s$ is **unitless**. Now, if you mix it by attaching $f$ with cycles/second, and $f_s$ with samples per second. And reach the conclusion that $f/f_s$ has a unit of *cycles/sample*; it may seem consistent but neither a *cycle* nor a *sample* is term for a unit.

Comment: @CedronDawg [cont]. Furthermore, attaching $f_s$ with *samples/second* should also be approached with care. On a typical drawing we draw a **frequency axis** onto which both arbitrary frequency *f* and the sampling frequqncy $f_s$ are placed (as is done ona Nyquist analysis of sampling). In this regard $f_s$ is no more different than just an ordinary frequency $f$ on that same axis. They both have th (physical) units of 1/s = Hz. Perhaps the *samples per second* usage is a sort of technical jargon leaked through mathematical designation of $f_s$ as a sampling **rate**. I mean not a big deal.

Comment: @CedronDawg **related rates** ;-))

Comment: @Fat32 See my followup. I'm still not resentful, hope you aren't either. I would argue strongly that it is (not just seems) consistent. Compared to "it seems you can prove the angle addition formulas from Euler's formula". It seems you can, but you can't since Euler's formula is dependent on the angle addition formulas. Then there's this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_per_second and this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency_(unit)

Comment: @CedronDawg why do you use *cycle/sec* for $f$, but *sample/sec* for $f_s$ while both are just two different frequencies? You have to answer this, and look at my **average** height computation example in th eabove comment. Read it carefully and disprove it. And clearly explain: 1-what a cycle is, 2-what a sample is, 3- why you chose them over standard SI Hz unit. Clearly explain them...

Comment: @Fat32 First observation since it arises from the true purpose of my question:  Notice your language ("You have to answer this").  Mandates tend to come from the PC side in any arena.  In context of the DFT, the numerator and denominator pertain to quite different concepts.  The denominator (the namer) designates the spacing of the sampling in the application framework (attribute of the tool).  The numerator (the counter) designates a propertiy of the signal being measured (target of the tool).  I don't see these things as the same at all.

Comment: (con't) Labeling units is subjective.  The desire for objectivity is a driving motivation for standardization, but at what cost?  In your example (and I had been waiting for Bob K. to make an appearance to let him take a stab at it), I would say there is no utility in explicity (no contextual distinction needs to be made) trying to label any unit other than your height unit.  You could label "N" with persons.  Then $\mu$ would have units of "cms/person".  The units of $\bar{x}_i$ [Unconventional use of bar, BTW, 50 lashes] would be "unitless" or "person" respectively.

Comment: (con't) In the former case, it would be okay to also say "non-dimensional height", just as Reynolds Number is called the non-dimensional velocity in Fluid Dynamics (Engineering College), or "normalized height" (unit) would be better.  I'm about 1.09 persons in the latter case, but without context that isn't very meaningful, or as I like to say "I'm five foot fifteen."

Comment: The very names used for a fraction, or rate, literally mean counter of named things, and $\frac{a}{b}$ can always be split into $a \cdot \frac{1}{b}$.  Understanding that makes the rules of adding and comparing fractions much easier to grasp.  (Sorry for the chat overrun).

Comment: @CedronDawg your mind blowing (and freely inconsistent as of your joyful desire) explanation on the **average height unit** definition is of the award requiring kind; clearly indicating your purpose of these discussions: *not making any positive contributions to the theory or practice of signal processing, and to community of its users, but just trolling it for some personal sake*.. I would like to stay out of these pointless discussions. Electrical Engineering is an established field, and what's counted as a legitimate contribution is well understood and appreciated.

Comment: Funny, I see my motivation as altruistic and coverage of this sorely needed.  For the mud splatter I have to endure to do this, a little bit of enjoyment is excusable I think.  YMMV.  If adhering to SI didn't cause space craft to crash, the confusion of what Hz means to newbies, etc. I wouldn't have said a thing.

Comment: @CedronDawg I can see the *personal* taste of my statements... I have nothing to do with you, or your choice of making these discussions, yet your attitude is not towards clarifying the concepts or problems, but rather *achieving some self-satisfaction from refusing the very well kown standards*, by using some **freely invented terminology** of yours. That's what I won't stand by to, for any reasons... sorry Ced.

Comment: Truthfully, I wouldn't have gotten into DSP in the first place if just one of the dozens of professors and experts had done the proper thing and actually looked at my math instead of dismissing it as impossible based on their erroneous preconceptions.  RB-J, PeterK, and Jacobsen are on that list.  Instead I wrote an academic paper, sound of crickets.  Then I started my blog as a rough draft for a textbook for learning the DFT without calculus and all the baggage of the continuous case.  Interested publishers, please call me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hertz** particularly refers to **time** rate of some repetitive event such as rotation. Whereas **Cycles per length** refer to **space** rate of some repetitive event such as a picture line bar pattern. Cycle simply means a repeating event, mostly a whole rotation of something, or a $2\pi$ increment in a sinusoidal argument. In most contexts, the word *cycles* can be replaced with the word *rotations* or *repetition*, or even just with *tics*.

So if you are sampling a continuous-time signal then your sampling rate is *Fs Hz*, or *Fs samples per second*.

Note that these two are exactly the same things. Since *samples* do not have a (physical) unit associated with it, (it's just a counting number) then *Fs samples per second* is dimensionally *Fs per second*, which is abbreivated as *Fs Hz*.

So they are the same things stated differently... Be consistent, and both should work well.

Furthermore note that, practically speaking sampling is carried out by ADC devices which are operated at different *clock frequencies* to achive the desired rate of sampling. Hence the *Hz*, usage is also quite sound way of describing it.

Finally, the *Hz* usage is linked more naturally with the analog (continuous-time) signal, whereas the *sample per second* usage is more linked with the discrete-time signal (sequence) nature.

Comment: Now a days I am using RPM, Hz is just too fast for me.
$$ ;-) $$
The issue of the actual question in the link in this question, is about whether the duration of the sampling interval should be first sample to last sample (N-1) or frame size (N).  Coincidently, if you care to follow, the same issue arises in different but related contexts here  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69430/amplitude-after-fourier-transform/69432#69432 and   here https://www.dsprelated.com/thread/11973/has-any-one-seen-this-window-function

Comment: Then use 1/60 Hz ;-))

Comment: Actually, the Hz/60/60/24 fly by too fast, even the Hz/60/60/24/365.25 are going by too fast.  Did you read the link?  It is about keeping units straight in their domains and Hz does not belong in the DFT as that is an application level unit, not tool level.  Calling samples per second Hz, as is frequently done (pun!), carries an implied "1 cycle per sample" conversion factor.  In the ADC or DAC arena, this is appropriate and known/mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @CedronDawg Can you write me a Matlab program that computes the *elevation* and *azimuth* angles of the Sun and the Moon on a given day-hour-minute (local hour corrected) at any place on Earth with a given latitude and longitude (and may be altitude too)..?

Comment: I don't do Matlab.  I've posted something similar in a Gambas forum: https://forum.gambas.one/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=720  In researching that I found all the formulas you are looking for.  I can't find the awesome Swedish site with all the very accurate coefficients I found before, but a search on "azimuth sun moon calculation coefficients" will give you plenty of material.

Comment: @CedronDawg Seems like a nice program thank you! I have downloaded the zip file, and will try to convert it to Matlab... I may return to you when things are done... ;-) I'm not interested in the "display" logic, but just calculations.

Comment: @CedronDawg Hi cedron, I've converted that code into matlab and it works! Great surprise! It finds sun set and sun rise and noon times wrt local time and time-zone. Yet the code has absolutely no explanations and introduces so many awkard variables without a definition. And mostly **hardcoded** constant literals that hardly make any sense. So I was looking for something more with an explanation of how it's calculated and definitions of all variables. Some geometric calculations I was looking for. I'm pretty it's doing it but the code is so much condensed and reduced into being helpful...

Comment: @CedronDawg Actuallt I've already written some codes based on Sun-Earth-Moon geometry and kinematics of planetary motion, I needed a lot of variables based on the astronomical parameters (such as axis tilt, orbit eccentricity, radius of Earth etc.) and  utilized some subtle vector operations to get azimuth-elevation angles of Sun / Moon. I'm looking for a refined means of calculating it and some calibrations. Your code (dunno who wrote it and how) calculates quite fine (not very accurate though). I cannot find a way to improve it though as it's quite peculiar to its owners.. ;-) any helps ?

Comment: I'm sorry, Fat32, this was long ago enough that I don't remember the specifics.  This is the link I cited in the code (comment at the top) math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186683/how-to-calculate-sunrise-and-sunset-times.  IIRC, the Swedish site I referenced had coefficients based on empirical data, but I do vaguely remember reading about some derivations.  That's the best I can do right now without further searching.

Comment: @CedronDawg ok many thanks for pointing into the resources... Btw. $f/f_s$ is of course unitless :-)) See my comments to BobK down ;-) [I want to stay out of this discussion but no it's hard to do so...]

Comment: I've added my own answer and gave the check to Bob K.  Neither RB-J's answer or mine address the title question directly.  My preference is everybody take this discussion to their respective watercoolers.  I would think it more interesting than "It sure is getting cold fast", or "How 'bout them Tigers?"  You should definitely stay away from "Wow, did you see the blouse the receptionist was wearing yesterday."  Nowadays, that can get you fired.  Will procreation drop to zero?

Answer (score 1):

This question wasn't really about the units of frequency.

The notion that a standards committee could hijack a common word, claim it as their own, and forbid other uses of it, is so arrogant and hubristic that it boggles my mind.  I don't care if it happened 60 years ago (about my age) or yesterday, what is wrong is wrong and when that is recognized if should be corrected.  And as they say, "I wasn't born yesterday."

Properly, "units" should remain as general as possible.  If you want to give a special meaning linguistically, it requires its own modifier.  Like "SI Units", or "standard units", or "basis units", etc.  Nobody, or no body, gets to say "these are the officially approved 'units' and everything else you used to consider a unit is now a 'factor label'"  Once that kind of control is ceded, it is never recovered and the control freaks get to have a field day.  And they won't stop there.  Whether OCD is a mental disease or a personality type doesn't matter, it is no excuse, and it isn't a hall pass.

Any quantity you measure, is measured on a scale and some reference is the unit with a "1" value and there is a "0" value.  Normalizing is simply a rescaling by picking a representative value and declaring it to be the new "1" on the new scale.  Thus, you are still measuring along the same dimension, all that has happened is a rescaling conversion factor has been defined and applied.  It does not all the sudden lose its dimensionality.  Even if you define a new origin, a new "0", you still just have a rescaling, but now with a bias.  It is still along the same dimension.

The notion that only officially approved "Dimensions" are allowable, is Orwellian to say the least.  Dimension is a scale type answering the quality (as in property or attribute) of that which is being measured.

A normalized frequency is still measuring frequency, just on a different scale.

A normalized height is still measuring height, just on a different scale.

Neither are unitless (a null concept, every scale has a unit) nor dimensionless (another null concept, every scale has a type).  Counting numbers are the tic marks on a scale, they are still in the same units in the same dimension.

Height is a different dimension than length.

It isn't this way because "Ced said so.", it is this way because this is the way it is.  If you think I got it wrong, then you need to argue on the merits, not appeal to authorities like governing bodies or textbook authors, or appeal to the crowd by saying this is the way everybody does it in our club.  You don't get to shoot the messenger either because you disagree with the message.

Words have meaning.  Sometimes the same word has a colloquial meaning and a technical meaning.  When the technical meaning diverges too far from the colloquial meaning you can tell a guild power play is in motion, and if you search further you'll find a control freak, or a gaggle of them, who want to rule their world.

Standards have benefits there is no doubt.  They also have the ability to be the foundation of tyranny.  They are a tool, a policy, a pre-defined decision, nothing more.  If you don't understand the rationale behind a policy you are likely to misapply it.  Law is crafted carefully (or should be) so the "spirit of the law" is not lost in "the letter of the law".  Policy is generally not that carefully wrought.

Now we have people running around with rulers measuring six feet down to the inch.  Pathetic.

And this ain't my first time at the rodeo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion can be explained as semantics, specifically the word "cycle" or "cycles".  In the context of signal frequency, such as the Nyquist frequency, it refers to one *period* of a continuous periodic signal.  And in the context of sampling, such as the Nyquist rate, Fat32 equates it to $T$, the sampling interval.  If we were to rename those units respectively as *periods* and *samples*, the units of normalized signal frequency, $f/f_s$, are *periods/sec / samples/sec = periods/sample*, which is not unitless (they don't cancel).  Therefore, the only disagreement here comes down to the common practice of substituting *cycles* for *periods*, and the uncommon (IMO) practice of substituting *cycles* for sample-intervals.

It might also be useful to recall how Oppenheim & Schafer, 2nd ed, 1999, pp 140-141 introduce sampling.

> $T$ is the sampling period, and its reciprocal, $f_s=1/T$, is the sampling
> frequency, in **samples per second**. [Note they never say Hz in relation
> to sampling, although (as Fat32 said) other authors do.].  We also
> express the sampling frequency as $\Omega_s = 2\pi/T$ when we want to use
> frequencies in radians per second.

The implied conversion factor from $f_s$ to $\Omega_s$ is $2\pi$ *radians per sample*, which only makes sense when *sample-interval* is synonymous with *cycle* (Fat32's semantic)... bringing us back to the semantic conflict.

Bottom line: *Hz/Hz = cycles/sec / cycles/sec* is not unitless when the numerator "cycles" has a different definition than the denominator "cycles".  Just having the same overloaded name is not mathematically sufficient for cancellation.

Comment: The problem is not about using *cycles* or *samples* sort of a unit designator; it's ok; it's used in practice for example in image processing where *cpm* (cycles per meter) refers to spatial frequency of image patterns. There we connot use Hz which strictly refers to *time* periodicity of an event. The problem is about making this a problem? The SI *dimension* of $f/f_s$ is none. Yet you can assign *anything* with $f$ and $f_s$ such as *f = periods/second* and *f_s = impulses / second* hence you will have *f/f_s = periods / impulse* as your new invented unit :-) we don't **need** it :-)

Comment: "Just having the same overloaded name is not mathematically sufficient for cancellation."  Bam, hits the target dead center.  The appeal to authority is supportive and sure doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Assuming Wiki is accurate, the SI model is definitionally incomplete.  In https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit, the table's right most column references "1" as a base unit (the equivalent in the header doesn't cover this)  The "official dimensions list" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units does not include "1".  So a new dimension is needed, maybe call it "Ordinal" or "Natural", with a base unit of "1".  This would obviate the term "dimensionless".

Comment: @Fat32 The previous comment is a separate question from "Should 'rotation' be an official dimension with 'radians' as the base unit?" In which I agree whole heartedly with Mohr and Phillips that it should. This would eliminate the immediate problem being highlighted by the title question. Interestingly, talking about "need" vs "want", introducing this dimension would eliminate the need for an "Ordinal" dimension.

Comment: @CedronDawg Don't assume wiki as accurate for a fundamental research ;-) *radian* is already included in the SI system as a unit of angle (as a geomteric construct). It's not a *base unit* but a supplementary one. Radian itself is considered as unitless due its definition being ratio of two lengths. Note that SI also recognises K (Kelvin), cd (candela) ,or Mole number as base-units, but it's known that they can be expressed in terms of other units and actually not true innovations. So these units are not that sort of fixed things, nor they are necessarily irreducible postulates of physics.

Comment: @Fat32 But it was on the internet so I know it must be true. ;-)  According to the article "supplementary" was retired, and is now "derived".  Oh, it's so hard to keep up.  I disagree with its definition being the ratio of two lengths.  The definition is from polar coordinates which are (radii,radians).

Comment: @Fat32 Furthermore, the ratio you speak of can be described as a normalization.  So the statement "Radians are the units of normalized arc lengths (where the normalization factor is based on the radius)" is true and accurate in my understanding.  Personally, the classification/categorization to the dimensional level is unimportant.  I also think the major error in "SI thinking" is extending the algebraic manipulation of the units up to the dimensional level.

Comment: Agree or disagree? "Unit conversions are done within a dimension, they don't change the dimension."  For anybody, not just Fat32.  This is supposed to be a discussion.

Comment: @CedronDawg f/fs is a normalization between the members of the same class/category (by definition of normalization they should be of comparable -same- type) therefore its' both **dimensionless** and **unitless** in the physical (egnineering) science. You associate it a unit based on defining a **ratio** between two different kinds of quantities. Just as *length/time* , *mass/time*, *mass/dollar*.. these are for **ratios** they are not *normalizations*. You mix normalization with a *ratio*. So if $f/f_s$ is called a **normalized** frequency, then it's unitless and dimensionless... I agree :-)

Answer (score 1):

I speak with no authority on this subject but interest in what the answer is- I found this table pasted below at this link [https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/units-and-dimension#:~:text=Dimensions%20are%20physical%20quantities%20that,relative%20unit%20that%20describes%20length](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/units-and-dimension#:%7E:text=Dimensions%20are%20physical%20quantities%20that,relative%20unit%20that%20describes%20length)).

Which lists the radian as a unit, but doesn't have a fundamental dimension. That said, are not the units of $f/f_s$ radians/sample if $f$ can be radians per second? (And is therefore dimensionless but not unitless?) Where in SI does it say that the units of radian frequency are not radians/second (and if it does say that, why does it if radians are a unit?). I understand how the dimension can be 1/s based on this but don't quite see how the units are lost.

[image: SI Units]

Comment: Ahh this fundamental research! Just reminds me of the claims to invent time-machine sorta things but will never show it to anyone because a patent was pending :-))) Have a look at physics with **vectors**. Let $\vec{A}$ be an electric field vector in units of V/m. We can express it like $\vec{A} = |A| \hat{a} $ where $|A|$ is its magnitude (in units of V/m) and $\hat{a}$ is a *unitless* unit vector along the direction of $\vec{A}$. Now the unit-vector $\hat{a}$ is a **ratio** $\hat{a} = \frac{\vec{A}}{|A|}$ hence it's **normalised** and therefore **unitless** just as unitless as f/fs should be

Comment: A **normalisation** by definition requires the comprasion (and division) of two similar things which should have same dimensions and units. Therefore the result will alwyas be dimensionless and unitless. Normalized Frequency **f/fs** is of no exception to this rule....

Comment: Just as unitless as decibells. Note that engineers assign units to dB scale too.. Such as dB mV, but that's a conventional usage and strictly speaking wrong... That only means that the reference voltage is 1 mV, but the ratio is unitless. something very helpful.

Comment: f/fs is a normalization between the members of the same class/category (by definition of normalization they should be of comparable -same- type) therefore its' both **dimensionless** and **unitless** in the physical (egnineering) science. If we associate it a unit based on defining a **ratio** between two different kinds of quantities. Just as *length/time* , *mass/time*, *mass/dollar*.. these are for **ratios** they are not *normalizations*. It's a mix of normalization with a *ratio*. So if $f/f_s$ is called a **normalized** frequency, then it's unitless and dimensionless...

Comment: @Fat32 Normalization is the process of defining a new scale based on a reference value on the old scale.  It is a ratio, and can be considered a conversion factor.  The new scale is not unit less, it has tic marks.  The same source scale can be normalized on different reference values.  So, it is "a normalized frequency" not "the normalized frequency", otherwise fistfights might break out on which reference value is the "True One".

Comment: @Fat32 but clearly there is a practical benefit of distinguishing between radians/sample and cycles/sample so using those terms as units-- how is that reconciled otherwise? Is this just semantics or is someone saying it is wrong to describe fractional frequency in units of radians/sample (or what do we use if "unit" is verboten?)

Comment: The conversion/normalization factor is "unitless/dimensionless", the result is not.

Comment: @CedronDawg it's better to consult a **measurement** book ;-) I believe you should delete this whole post (with answers too) and if necessay re-ask it in a way clear and focused manner. Then we shall collect the best answers with their convincing and consistent explanations... f/f_s is a **normalisation** and it produces unitless numbers to be processed by mathematical algorithms... Anyway. this is waay too much for such a topic... I don't understand why you reject the unitless definition..? or why you associate f and fs with different sets. They belong to same set. Same units.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't seen this before, but why not have an argument (or a *"discussion"*) about dimensional analysis in the mainspace?  rather than the metaspace?

It looks like we're going down that way regarding DFT periodicity again.

@PeterK what do you think we should do about some contentious topics about hard-core mathematics and physics?  Engineering practice is another thing with legit differences of opinion, but I find it sorta goofy when it's math and classical physic.

Comment: This is not a question about dimensional analysis, it is about unit analysis.  They are not the same thing.  Dimensional analysis is much weaker, it can't even tell the difference between an inch and a mile as both are units of distance.  More germane, it can't tell the difference between a sample and a cycle.  Notice the question has "units" in it, not "dimension".  You seem to have missed that point when made in the main section as well.  Both are intended as integrity checks for formulas and calculations, unit analysis is better at that.  Search on "NASA's Mars Climate Orbiter".

Comment: I'm sorry Ced.  but while *units* are a thing, *"unit analysis"* is not a thing.  There are no units attached to $2$ or $2 \pi$ or the like.  The are just pure numbers.  Dimensionless numbers.  It's possible that when someone is self taught, that there are no checks on when they taught themselves a false thing.

Comment: i'd like to see you persuade any mathematician that either $2$ or $\pi$ are anything other than dimensionless numbers.  or that radians are anything other than a dimensionless measure.  it's a silly position to take.  one that i am sure is self-taught. $$ $$ i know it's hard to unlearn things.

Comment: i don't know for sure what you're thinking but if my guess is correct, the *"dimensionless units" such as *percent* (%) or *degree* (°) or even the *decibel* ($\mathrm{dB}$), all those "units" are, are a convention in that the symbol is equal to a ***dimensionless*** conversion factor. ... "%"$=\frac{1}{100}$. ...  "°"$=\frac{\pi}{180}$. ... and "$\mathrm{dB}$" $=\frac{\log(10)}{20}$ and those are just numbers.

Comment: and Ced, you are a lousy judge of your own expertise.

Comment: Once you go ad hominem, I'm done.  I was going to say if you concede that a radian is a unit, what is its dimension, but don't bother replying, I'm done.

Comment: the term "radian" is a semantic.  angles measured as *"radian"* are dimensionless quantities that are the ratio of two like-dimensioned lengths: the arc-length divided by the radial arm length.  there is no unit.

Comment: Here is an equation that should be familiar to you:
$$ 2\pi \cdot f \cdot t = \theta $$
Here it is carrying units:
$$ 2\pi \frac{\text{ Radians }}{\text{ Cycle }}  \cdot f \frac{\text{ Cycles }}{\text{ Second }} \cdot t \text{ Seconds } = \theta \text{ Radians } $$
Carrying units was taught in Junior High School for me, not self-taught.  Same was used in High School.  Same was used in College.   It works.  It is very useful for integrity checking formulas, and in performing calculations.

Comment: Dimensional analysis is a generalization and pedantic formalization of this.  Less specific = weaker.
$$ $$
Other conversion factors carrying units:
$$ 1 = 12 \frac{\text{ Eggs }}{\text{ Dozen }} = 12 \frac{\text{ Persons }}{\text{ Jury }} 
= 12 \frac{\text{ Months }}{\text{ Year }}$$
The "1" is what is unitless.  It can be multipied into any term in any equation.  Not that hard to understand.
$$ $$
In the NASA's Mars Climate Orbiter crash, the dimensions matched, but not the units.

Comment: In dimensions, it's:

$$ \text{none} \cdot \text{time}^{-1} \cdot  \text{ time } = \text{ none } $$

In Dimensional Analysis default units, it's:

$$ \text{none} \cdot \text{sec}^{-1} \cdot  \text{ sec } = \text{ none } $$

Okay, it tests true, but it isn't very powerful a test.

Comment: @CedronDawg I had put this in my answer but removed, let me add it here: *dimensional analysis* and *units* are **physical** things. Dimensional analysis: if LHS of an equality has the following dimension $ \frac{ V^2 \cdot m^3 \cdot kg}{s^2 \cdot C }$ then the RHS must also have the same *dimension*. Checking the validity of this is called a *dimensional analysis*.  **Units** (SI units, fundamental or base units) are accepted as:  m, kg, s, A, K, mole,cd... two supplementry defs are: radian and streradian. Also it's noted that K,cd and mole could be eliminated...

Comment: @CedronDawg your mass has a *unit* of kg. Your height has a unit of m, your velocity has a dimension and derived unit of m/s. Your momentum has a derived unit of kg*m/s which is the dimension of it as well... etc...

Comment: @CedronDawg and finally I never heard of something called a *unit analysis* before... It's probably same thing as a dimension analysis with **conversion factors**.

Comment: @Fat32 "Dimensional Analysis" is a title.  "unit analysis" is a descrtiptive phrase (better known as "carry they units"), "Unit Analysis" isn't serious.  I grew up on carrying the units (should be a common experience) and was only introduced to DA the first time RB-J tried to teach me his religion.  That's why I put the "this ain't about DA" in my question itself.  I read up on it, decided it was inferior, and didn't take it much further.  Mind your units and the dimensions will take care of themselves.

Comment: (con't) One big criticism of DA is that the dimensions are labeled/identified by their default units as you just demonstrated.  So, is "Dimensional Analysis" really "dimensional analysis", or is it really "unit analysis" in disguise?  This naming restriction really makes the dimensionless case really problematic.  Do you disagree with how I either carried the units or did the Dimensional Analysis of the $2\pi f t = \theta$ formula?

Comment: sorry, @Fat32, but while i think we both realize there's a bunch of poppycock in this whole question (it should have been obvious when Ced says that pure numbers such as $2$ or $2\pi$ have units or when Ced said that there was an implicit conversion factor applied to $f_\mathrm{s}$ when it is added to $f$, all this is pedantic bullshit that engineering professors would have to unteach students), the fact is that "**Units**" are themselves also only a anthropometric construct.  Units are not physical.  Physical quantity is physical, but units are not.

Comment: (con't) I did a little more searching and came across these discussions, which are very much on this topic and interesting, from quite a while back.  
https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/09/dimensional_analysis.html 
https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2006/09/dimensional_analysis_and_coord.html
RB-J makes an appearance as well which made me chuckle a little.  The postings are actually on someone's blog (John Baez) and he seems to be reading the same playbook as me but several chapters ahead.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yes I was unfortunately restrictive about **units** there. However when I said they are physical, I didin't mean they have phsyical existance :-) but instead I meant they are used to scale physical quantities. So we have non-physical units of bits, bytes, and MACs, samples, etc. And yes *units* is an abstract (anthropometric) construct without a physical existance on their own :-)

Comment: @CedronDawg actually a *dimension* is more general than a *unit*. So **length** is a dimension, but it has many different units such as meter, foot, yard, inch etc. Mass is a dimension and it also had many units throughout history. Time also had different units untill the second was adopted universally. So dimensional analysis is more general than the one with explicit units and conversion factors. I'm reading these from Ohanian Physics 2E expanded,ch1: Measurement of Space, Time , and Mass... I highly suggest this book for any scientist or engineer.

Comment: @Fat32  Yes, I made that point earlier to RB-J but deleted the comment.  There is a one to many between Dimensions and Units.  So, my naming comment above really came from database normalization principles.  It's why I also did both "time" (dimension), and "sec" (unit) in my equation example.  And I made the smarmy statement "Also, the application is not always in seconds, or time for that matter." at the end of the original post of https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/dft-exercise-in-the-book-understanding-digital-signal-processing-3-ed/69233?noredirect=1#comment144830_69233

Comment: @CedronDawg yes I realized it after posting my comment, sorry for that. Now my final words on units/dimensions is this : $2\pi$ is a number (quantifically 6.28..) without a unit. **Angles** do have units such as *Degree, Grad, Radian*. When your numbers refer to an angle, then their unit (actually a *scale*) is, say, radian: 3 radians, 5 radians or $2\pi$ radians. I find the **cycles** thing as quite unnecessary. Never seen it in any math,physics, eng book. But as long as it works for you. Thats ok.

Comment: @Fat32  The links have sufficient coverage of this topic and I don't have that much interest.  I'll say this:  There are $2\pi$ radius lengths in a circumference.  There are 12 inches in a foot.  Anything you count, you are counting units of it.  (Unit means "one" essentially).  Some things come in fractional quantities, yet the scale remains in units of those things.  "More or fewer", "greater or less", whether discrete or continuous, comparisons can only be made along the same dimension in the same units, likewise with sums.

Comment: i have deleted no comments in this thread and consider the deletion of a comment to be on the spectrum of disingenuous.  (unless one is asked to delete a comment that someone finds offensive or similar.)  we should all stand by what we say and if we figured out that we said something incorrect or wrong or foolish, just correct yourself and move on.

Comment: @Fat32 , i think we are on the same page.  "cycles" or "samples" or "ticks" are **things** that we count.  when we count them in time, there is a rate.  whether it's "Hz" (or "cycles/sec") or "samples/sec" or "ticks/sec", the **dimension** is $\mathrm{T}^{-1}$ and the common unit is "$\frac{1}{\mathrm{s}}$" or "$\mathrm{s}^{-1}$".  it may be wrong, but it **is** meaningful to add *"ordinary frequency"* to *"angular frequency"* because they are the same dimension.  it would be like adding the number of km to the number of miles.  but it's usually wrong unless you put in a conversion factor.

Comment: but where Ced is wrong and always had been (we had argued about stuff like this on *comp.dsp* as recently as 2017) is that there are units attached to dimensionless numbers and that sample rate is not compatible with Hz.  whenever you can add, subtract, or compare commensurate quantities, they are the same dimension.  and if you can correctly add them without a numerical conversion factor, then they have exactly the same units.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yeah we agree here... don't know about your past with Ced on comp.dsp :-)). I find his way of attaching units to everything in DSP as making things more complex than they actually are... At one point I fear if *units of units* will appear such as : velocity = meter / s = meter per coordinate scale / second per coordinate scale... where coordinate scale is a relativistic concern :-)

Comment: @CedronDawg ok but I thing being a mathematician you should step back a little on this topic of **physics** and engineering... When you say *I bought 2 kgs of apples*, apples is not a unit right ;-) at least in the **sense** that we tend to associate within the **physical science**... Defining a rate such as *how many apples per dollar* will you get, is not about considering apples as a unit in the sense that I tend to use it. It's just a mathematical rate. Otherwise yes, apples and oranges are different things of their own nature and we can attach their type names as units in computations.

Comment: @Fat32 I've added a followup to my question.  I hope I have explained things clearly enough that I can step away without any more heckling.  If you want to see my contribution to physics, check out https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1190.php (Shameless self-promotion).

Comment: Simply put, you can't add samples and cycles unless you recognize that there is one sample per cycle.

Comment: @Fat32  To me, this means that matter is composed of "photons" captured in each other's "fluff wakes".  I haven't gotten to the point where I can rectify this interpretation with contemporary theory but I conjecture that is possible.   I do note that CERN recently announced it had produced particles (stable flow configuration) from light.  Studying the eigenvector of the DFT vs the Hermite-Gaussian functions is part of that quest.

Comment: @CedronDawg I read your article. It sounds fine.Iignoring several points (cal of variations, Euler-Lagrange eq.), I see that you apply vector calculus operators to solve some classical equtions to find the shortest path for the light in **non-isotropic** medium. Recall that "n" is a Tenor of rank-2, but I can't see if you have utilized this. Also I can't make much sense of Eqs 6,7,13,and 18. Also I can't see what's accomplished in your solution? Did you solve an unsolvable problem in physics? It's not stated clearly. But otherwise, yes that's a good amount vector calculus of variations :-)

Comment: @Fat32, *//making things more complex than they actually are//* -- it's actually worse than making things more complex than they actually are.  it's erroneous which becomes obvious when Ced says that pure mathematical numbers like $2$ or $2\pi$ have units.  or that $f_\mathrm{s}$ has different units than $f$ when we are adding them directly together.  that pendantry will lead other pendants down the wrong path and they will later have to unlearn crap they picked up from Ced.

Comment: RB-J, you have yet to demonstrate that anything I have said is erroneous, only loudly proclaiming it is heretical and must be vanquished else others may be tainted.  Tighter integrity checking requires higher informational content, no way around that.  How "complicated" that is remains in the eye of the beholder.  I deleted the comments because they seemed too "braggish" upon rereading.  The discussion should be about the message, not the messenger.  I'm tired of your heckling and proselytizing.

Comment: @Fat32 Brief explanation:  (6) is part of the E-L definition.  (7) Is the "slick trick", (18) is the crown jewel and is the result of a unit conversion from (13).  (13) and (18) say that the acceleration of the particle occurs in a plane (or line) defined by the gradient of the index of refraction and the velocity of the particle.  I was motivated by considering that Snell's law was physically impossible, there had to be a little curvature to that bend.  So you can think of (13) and (18) as the vector differential form of Snell's law.  "n" is assumed to be real as a simplifying assumption.

Comment: (con't) I had to throw away half of the article due to the concept of anisotropism. The speed of the particle under the definition "c/n" is isotropic, the same in all directions. I derived the solution for the Schwarzschild Solution in the radial direction (and it is similar) and thought I had it made, but it turned out not to be that simple. Still a work in progress. The equation can also be applied, with some tweaking, to the propagation of sound waves in water with varying salinity conditions. So it is a general principle.  I don't know if it could be considered solving anything unsolved.

Comment: @CedronDawg I cannot justify by myself why Eq. 6 & 7 should be true, I think they are but don't know why. Also there's a *potential* function you talk about, what potential function is that, I can't see as well.Finally is really true that if F = 1, F is a constant, then how & why do you set its derivative ? I mean isnt it dF/dx = 0 ? But Eqs. 8 & 9 say dF/dq is nonzero ? So how come F = 1 for all q ? There are various such puzzles that I cannot find their justification...

Comment: @Fat32 No worries, you can email if you want to discuss it further, or post in Physics.SE and notify me.  (6) is part of the definition of the "Calculus of Variations".  This was my first real deep dive into it, and it confirmed my earlier Newtonian approach. (7) The nature of the "slick trick" (the product has to be constant, but not the constituent factors within their respective frames) is the nature of the slick trick and does indeed take some pondering to wrap your head around.  I have not found (13) and (18) anywhere else.  Nobody has refuted them yet.

Comment: Oh, the potential function is the value of the index of refraction (fluff density on the log scale) at every point.  It has a gradient which is a conservative vector field.

Comment: @CedronDawg so yo call "n" as a potential function ! :-) Never heard that before. Let me visit my electromagnetic books for that :-). I cannot get the *slick trick* on wikipedia. I have no idea of why it should be that way true or useful...:-))

Comment: Nothing I have said violates the "The factor-label method for converting units" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis.  (@Fat32, is a kg of NOx like a kilo of apples?)  Furthermore, the Huntley and Siano extensions in the end bring DA definitions of dimension more in line with math ones.  And the biggest annoyance is your continued insistence that "units are being attached to a number".  What units did I attach to 12?

Comment: (con't) Also from the article, "Then when adding two quantities of like dimension, but expressed in different units, the appropriate conversion factor, which is essentially the dimensionless 1, is used to convert the quantities to identical units so that their numerical values can be added or subtracted."  Yeah, that's what I said, and you denied.  Guess what, sometimes the conversion factor has a magnitude of 1.  That doen't make it disappear until you categorize from the unit level to the dimension level.

Comment: Finally, did Ted's wife divorce him? And quit using "neanderthal" in a disparaging manner.  (There's my first mandate compared to many from you.)

Comment: @CedronDawg I'm out of this discussion. I will use the notation found in the standard DSP texts, and IEEE standards. You know it's all about standards. Units do not have **absolute** meanings. Only relative. And I think that's the onto-epistemological-metaphysical mistake we are making here: trying to attach absolute meanings to things which only have binding-relations to objects/purpose they represent. What's the absolute meaning of the word *apple*? The only meaning is it represents a fruit which we **agreed** to call an apple. So keep up the standards and avoid useless discussions :-)).

Comment: now RB-J, when are you going to answer my question?  What are the units, not dimensions, or translation to common units, the actual units of $f/f_s$?  If I were you I would delete this answer and answer again without the distraction.  I don't mind all these comments disappearing.  (Seems you like to Karen the comment policy at Physics.SE too).  You don't seem to be the type to say "Uncle, I'm sorry."  Even after being incorrect all these years.  The misperceptions  belong to you, and the unlearning is yours to do.  Yeah, it can be difficult, but I'm rooting for you.

Comment: @CedronDawg I know it's weird but I have to repeat RBJ's comment here: *but where Ced is wrong and always had been (we had argued about stuff like this on comp.dsp as recently as 2017) is that there are units attached to dimensionless numbers and that sample rate is not compatible with Hz. whenever you can add, subtract, or compare commensurate quantities, they are the same dimension. and if you can correctly add them without a numerical conversion factor, then they have exactly the same units.*

Comment: @Fat32 Okay.  How did you determine that the quantities could be added without a conversion factor?

Comment: @CedronDawg You cannot even determine that 1+0=1 unless you **accept** some unprovable postulates which are accepted to be true by their own. This is not such an important topic. **Numbers** are unitless mathematical things and when they refer to physical quantities they will have units based on the nature of the quantity. Throughout sampling theorem $f+f_s$ or $f-f_s$ are arithmetically added without no conversion factors.

Comment: @Fat32 The answer isn't "Because Ced said so."  Real Analysts would disagree about the importance.  I'm done here.

Comment: @CedronDawg Real Analysts cannot even answer the question how come the algebraically (and arithmetically) illegal statement 0/0 produce anything valid or meaningful in the mystery of the non-mathematical thing called *limit*. Mathematicians should answer their very own fundamental philosophical problems, (or abondon calculus all together ) before trying to deal with others'... ;-)

Comment: @Fat32 1+0=1 is the first step in Real Analysis, not my favorite (by far) branch of Mathematics.  0/0 is covered extensively, from all directions.  No need for me to explain it.  Have a nice day!  (My second mandate)  Don't expect any more replies here.

Comment: @CedronDawg **answer**:  *1+0=1 is the first step in Real Analysis. 0/0 is covered extensively, from all directions. No need for me to explain it.* If this accounts for an **answer** , then f/fs is first step in DSP and covered across all textbooks as unitless is just a legitimate answer too :-)) So the topic is closed! well-done; -) have a nice day too Ced.

Comment: @Fat32://Throughout sampling theorem $f+f_s$ or $f-f_s$ are arithmetically added with no conversion factors.//  **No.** In general, you are referring to something like $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X\left(f - \frac{k}{T}\right)$, where $T$ has units of *sec/sample*, and therefore $k$ has units of *cycles/sample*.  Choosing the case $k=1$ to make it invisible does not change its invisible units.

Comment: @BobK I don't take it. Associating a unit with a summation index is the first of a kind I heard from you... Your units are redundant. It's sufficient to associate units of *f with 1/s*, *T = 1/f = seconds* and k is a unitless summation index *number*. You lose nothing by the simplicty and you gain nothing by your redundancy... No need to discuss this. Pew associating *k* with a unit ! :-)) Only a pure mathematician could do that :-)

Comment: //No need to discuss this.//  Happily, because we live in different worlds.  In mine, things like samples and cycles actually exist, as they also do in EE textbooks.  And *redundancy* (as you call it) is actually a helpful thing.  And BTW I've never been mistaken for "a pure mathematician" before.  I think of that as someone who would rather **not** associate k with a unit.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
x_\mathrm{s}(t) &\triangleq T \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \delta(t-nT) \\
\\
X_\mathrm{s}(f) &= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} X(f - k\,f_\mathrm{s}) \qquad \text{where} f_\mathrm{s} \triangleq \frac{1}T \\
\end{align}$$

are there objections to that?  do we agree on the definition of the continuous Fourier Transform that relates all the x's together?  And @BobK, you're also saying that $f$ and $f_\mathrm{s}$ have different units?  (BTW, we old timers are joking a little about this on Facebook. We remember "Nordic God". May I add BobK to the mix?)

Comment: @BobK *pure mathematician* had a kind of humor in it, in the sense that *he's somone who spends his entire time on "unitless" quantities so much to the extend that at some point he gets crazy and makes up his own units to associate even with summation indices, as they are the main objects he is dealing with...* ;-) I must attach a unit to my numbers !!!

Comment: [for uniform rotation, Mills correctly defines the revolution frequency as the number of complete revolutions, N, divided by the time interval, he takes the unit for N to be ‘cycle’ (which he defines as one revolution) rather than the correct unit: the number one. The unit for ‘frequency’ then appears to be ‘cycle per second’ (i.e. revolution per second), whereas it should be one per second, correctly called hertz. ..](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016Metro..53.1281L/abstract)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson don't know what to say... I beleve this thread should totally be deleted... And if necessary (which I don't think so) it could be reposted with a clean and focused style... and providing only **cited** answers instead of *personal views* (ad hominem!)... Besides, I believe this (dsp.se) is not the place to discuss a *revolutionary invention*, rather a place to provide answers based on the *current state of the field* ...

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson //you're also saying that $f$ and $f_s$ have different units?// At the risk of the dreaded redundancy, yes.  In terms of a continuous sinusoid (for instance), $f$ (in Hz) is the average number of periods it completes per second.  When we sample it at intervals of $T$ sec/sample, $f_s = 1/T$ samples/sec is the average number of samples taken per second.  *periods/sec* and *samples/sec* are different units. //We remember "Nordic God". May I add BobK to the mix?//  Whatever that is, no thanks.

Comment: reverse the spelling of both words.  Ced has some history with *comp.dsp*.  BobK has history with Wikipedia.  both grossly overesteem their own competence and expertise.

Comment: ...spoken by the guy who can't comprehend the difference between $\ \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n + kN]\ $ and $x[n \bmod N]$  (see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/about-discrete-fourier-transform-vs-discrete-fourier-series/69952#699520)

Comment: who are you quoting?  and what is the quote?

Comment: If you are finally ready to abandon that indefensible position, great!  Follow the link (above) to the comments under my Aug 25 14:04 answer, and apologize for being adamantly incorrect for the last 6 years.

Comment: @BobK, you're full of shit.  And you're making a few people other than me laugh.  Now I can be expected to account for things that I say.  But I will not account for things that I don't say, nor about ambiguous insinuated references.  In your comment above, what is it that I said in the cited post (or any other post of mine that you cite) that you expect me to account for?  That implies a lack of comprehension?  **You** need to account for what **you** say.

Comment: I just did that... it's all on the record.  I would need to check with Fat32 before a 3rd repetition, because he/she chastises me for my affinity for *redundancy*.  Fun times here!

Comment: You said: *"spoken by the guy who can't comprehend the difference between..."* (and some math that i am not going to punch in).  Now, what is it that I said that is demonstrative of something that you need also cite in your claim of something I *"can't comprehend"*?  Again, **you** also need to account for what you say.  You don't get a pass.

Comment: Funnier yet, reverse "Ced" phonetically.  Oh so many layers.  "If you get down and you quarrel everyday
You're saying prayers to the devils, I say, wooh ", Bob Marley.

Answer (score -1):

This is my second answer and it addresses the title question.

Let's leave dimensions out of it, as I intended with the question, and leave it at the unit level.  Let's also leave Hz out of it, since there is a non-SI definition (cycles per second) and a SI definition ('one' per second).

Let the number of samples taken in one second be $f_s$.

$$ f_s \text{ samples } = 1 \text{ second }  $$

Both sides can be divided by the LHS:

$$ 1 = \frac{ 1 \text{ second } }{ f_s \text{ samples } } =  \frac{ 1 }{ f_s } \; \frac{ \text{ seconds } }{ \text{ sample } } $$

This is now a conversion factor, it converts samples to seconds.

There is a signal, suppose it has a frequency in cycles per second of $f$.  Applying the conversion factor yields:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ second } }  &= f \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ second } } \cdot 1 \\
&= f \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ second } } \cdot \frac{ 1 }{ f_s } \; \frac{ \text{ seconds } }{ \text{ sample } } \\
&= \frac{ f }{ f_s } \; \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ sample } } \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The signal's frequency has now been converted to a new unit of cycles per sample with a value of $ f/f_s $

The boss comes around and says the implementation team needs the units to be radians per sample so they can plug it into the wondrous cycle machine.

No problem, just introduce another conversion factor:

$$ 2 \pi \text{ radians } = 1 \text{ cycle }  $$

Both sides can be divided by the RHS and reversed:

$$ 1 = \frac{ 2 \pi \text{ radians } }{ 1 \text{ cycle } } =  2 \pi \frac{ \text{ radians } }{ \text{ cycle } } $$

$$
\begin{aligned}
   \frac{ f }{ f_s } \; \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ sample } } \cdot 1
&= \frac{ f }{ f_s } \; \frac{ \text{ cycles } }{ \text{ sample } } 2 \pi \frac{ \text{ radians } }{ \text{ cycle } } \\
&= \frac{ f }{ f_s } 2 \pi  \; \frac{ \text{ radians } }{ \text{ sample } } \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Report back to the boss:

The signal's frequency is  $ 2 \pi f/f_s   $ in units of radians per sample, just as you wanted, boss.

Meanwhile, Roger, does the calculation the SI way, and reports:

The frequency is a unitless $ f/f_s $

The boss says to Roger, I need that in radians per sample.

What does Roger do?

Comment: He gets promoted to HR, of course.  Happy Equinox everybody.  Any one want to hear the one about the family recipe for "Seagull in a Boot"? (Please don't upvote this answer, I want it to stay at the bottom.)